# Cannot connect to microservice from Api Gateway using Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, netflix-eureka, gateway

I created a microservices environment, consisting of a user microservice, an api gateway, eureka, and Rabbitmq.

I then dockerized each one and ran the images on their own EC2 instances.

Everything works correctly, the services register in eureka, connect correctly to the rabbit server and can make use of cloud config. In addition, configure inbound rules so that microservices can connect to each other.

When I send a request using only the user microservice to create a user or login a user, it works correctly.

The problem is that when I use the gateway api to make use of the user microservices I get this error:

```
2023-08-30T21:58:05.533Z ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [3271cd96-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/users/login"

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /172.17.0.2:8181
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/users/login" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:166) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:131) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:359) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:710) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:687) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:489) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
`2023-08-30T21:58:05.533Z ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [3271cd96-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/users/login"

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /172.17.0.2:8181
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/users/login" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:166) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:131) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:359) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:710) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:687) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:489) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar!/:4.1.94.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

What I find strange is that it says that Connection refused: /172.17.0.2:8181
This confuses me because if I am making the request correctly I should be sending the request to {ms-aws-ip}:8181

[Also, I noticed a difference between the tutorial I am following and what I see on my Eureka screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkA8W.jpg)
I see that the person who is doing the tutorial can see the client links to the aws instances in Eureka with the next format ip-xx.xx.xx.xx.ec2.internal:users:8181

These are the application.properties of the microservices, with their configuration running on localhost. At the time of running the docker images I change the configs so they can connect with each other.

EUREKA:

```
server.port=8010
spring.application.name=discoveryservice
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka
```

USERS:

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=users
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
```

GATEWAY:

```
server.port=8083
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-status-check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://users
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[2]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=users-create-user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://users
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/users
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

I tried adding this to the microservices and didn't work: eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true

Answer (score 0):

i just change the apploication.properties to application.yml ther's plugin that ca n handel that by the way , and now it work correctly